# Sample code for Anymote in C++ version?

Tags: c++, ios, arm, google-tv

Can anyone tell me where to find the resource just like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git%2FAnymoteLibrary%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fgoogle%2Ftv%2Fanymotelibrary%2Fclient)

(But I hope this is for C++ !!)

There is a dynamic library under google tv chrome extersion [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-chrome-extensions/source/browse/AnymoteExample/?r=2048c59701bab6386f7ea8011e4ca342fb1f133a#AnymoteExample%2Fplugins%2Fgtvremote_AnymoteExample.plugin%2FContents%2FMacOS)

This hyperlink tells us how to go Anymote by call C++ libraries through NPAPI under javascript.
Maybe I can follow this page to go under C++ version.
Unfortunately, the arch of these libraries is i386 (or x86_64).
My project build under the other platform (ex: arm), so I can't call these libraries directly.  Orz

Comment: @Joshi 
   ...so I summarize your comment and my conjecture:
1. The source code in C++ branch of anymote-protocol project is just an incomplete library, right ? There are so many virtual function, interface and headers. 
2. We need to implement these abstract class of anymote library if we want to use the it. 
3. There is a c++ version library in gtv-chrome-extension project for javascript client , but this c++ library did not open source.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cpp Anymote library implementation and some unittests which exercise the library APIs at:

http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/source/browse/#hg%2Fcpp

Apart from that there is no open source Anymote client library in C++.

Comment: I have watched this page in anymote project before, and I already build this source to static library. I need some tutorial to tell me how to use these API, e.g. call steps . There are many different between C++ and Java in API layer, so it is so hard to reference client app in Java version. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: BTW, you mean 'unittests which API exercise' just like this?
[devicesessiontest.cc](
http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/source/browse/cpp/tests/anymote/device/devicesessiontest.cc)